# Trying to get a new array based on two older ones but I get the following error: .push is not a function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a new array based on two old ones. So I have storywords array, and unecessarywords array. And I want to make a new betterwords array based on taking out the unecessarywords from storywords.  My code is as follows:

```
let betterWords = [];

for (let u_words_i = 0; u_words_i < unnecessaryWords.length; u_words_i++) {
  for (let story_i = 0; story_i < storyWords.length; story_i++) {
    if (storyWords[story_i] != unnecessaryWords[u_words_i]) {
    betterWords = betterWords.push(storyWords[story_i]);
  }
  }
};
console.log(betterWords);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! `betterWords = betterWords.push(storyWords[story_i]);` should be `betterWords.push(storyWords[story_i]);`. `push` returns a number, so that overwrites the array and then you try to call `number.push`.

Comment: Ok, but isn´t .push suppose to add an item to the last part of the array?    can you please specify why you say that push returns a number?

Comment: According to [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push): "The push method appends values to an array. Return value: The new length property of the object upon which the method was called."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ggorlen is right. You don't need to assign after pushing.

Also Just wanted to make a quick remark regarding your code. It could be improved to be much more readable like so:

```js
const betterWords = storyWords.filter(word => !unnecessaryWords.includes(word));
```